# Which version of Tensorflow and Keras should I install so that 'load_model' will work properly?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Which version of Tensorflow and Keras should I install so that 'load_model' will work properly???
I currently have below specification:
Tensorflow==2.12.0
Keras==2.3.1

Tried this one, still not working
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model

Answer (score 0):

> Which version of Tensorflow and Keras should I install so that
> 'load_model' will work properly???

You can install the updated version of tensorflow ,keras and numpy.

please find the below screenshort. where i use tensorflow = 2.15.0,keras = 3.0.2 ,numpy = 1.23.5

[image]

you can refer to the official TensorFlow guide and keras :- [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) and [keras](https://keras.io/getting_started/)